# Python web scraping error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So, I try to do web scraping from https://www.goodreads.com/list/show/83612.NY_Times_Fiction_Best_Sellers_2015.
This is html that I get from html parsing :

```
<td valign="top" width="100%">
    <a class="bookTitle" href="/book/show/18143977-all-the-light-we-cannot-see" itemprop="url">
        <span aria-level="4" itemprop="name" role="heading">All the Light We Cannot See</span>
    </a> <br>
    <span class="by">by</span>
    <span itemprop="author" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
        <div class="authorName__container">
            <a class="authorName" href="https://www.goodreads.com/author/show/28186.Anthony_Doerr" itemprop="url">
                <span itemprop="name">Anthony Doerr</span>
            </a> <span class="greyText">(Goodreads Author)</span>
        </div>
    </span>
    <br />
    <div>
        <span class="greyText smallText uitext">
            <span class="minirating">
                <span class="stars staticStars notranslate">
                    <span class="staticStar p10" size="12x12"></span>
                    <span class="staticStar p10" size="12x12"></span>
                    <span class="staticStar p10" size="12x12"></span>
                    <span class="staticStar p10" size="12x12"></span>
                    <span class="staticStar p3" size="12x12"></span>
                </span> 4.32 avg rating — 1,622,659 ratings</span>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div style="margin-top: 5px">
        <span class="smallText uitext">
            <a href="#" onclick="Lightbox.showBoxByID('score_explanation', 300); return false;">
                score: 12,706
            </a>,
            <span class="greyText">and</span>
            <a href="#" id="loading_link_849498" onclick="new Ajax.Request('/list/list_book/4645304', {asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true, onFailure:function(request){Element.hide('loading_anim_849498');$('loading_link_849498').innerHTML = '&lt;span class=&quot;error&quot;&gt;ERROR&lt;/span&gt;try again';$('loading_link_849498').show();;Element.hide('loading_anim_849498');}, onLoading:function(request){;Element.show('loading_anim_849498');Element.hide('loading_link_849498')}, onSuccess:function(request){Element.hide('loading_anim_849498');Element.show('loading_link_849498');}, parameters:'authenticity_token=' + encodeURIComponent('6lhx6sV5qy11Lg1m0knlIiiBHvcno5EeLkBs5xzr5p9R3JgvjO2eYcBCjOVqr2bMfLnqe+8H9kU+pGpxJ4wsPw==')}); return false;">
                128 people voted
            </a>
            <img alt="Loading trans" class="loading" id="loading_anim_849498" src="https://s.gr-assets.com/assets/loading-trans-ced157046184c3bc7c180ffbfc6825a4.gif" style="display:none" />
             

        </span>
    </div>
    </br>
</td>
```

And this is the code that I use for web scraping

```
import bs4
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

myurl = "https://www.goodreads.com/list/show/83612.NY_Times_Fiction_Best_Sellers_2015"
myurl

uClient = uReq(myurl)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

tds = page_soup.findAll("td", {"width":"100%","valign":"top"})

for td in tds :
    juduls = td.a.select("span")
    judul = juduls[0].text
    print(judul)
    authors = td.div.select("a")
    author = authors[0].text
    print(author)
    rates = td.findAll("span", {"class":"greyText smallText uitext"})
    rating = rates[0].text.strip().replace(",",".")
    print(rating)
    scores = td.findAll("div", {"style":"margin-top: 5px"})
    score = scores[0].span.a.text.strip().replace("score: ","").replace(",",".")
    print(score)
    votes = td.findAll("div", {"style":"margin-top: 5px"})
    vote = votes[0].find("a", {"id":"loading_link_849498"}).text.strip()
    print(vote)
```

result :

```
All the Light We Cannot See
Anthony Doerr
4.32 avg rating — 1.622.659 ratings
12.706
128 people voted
The Nightingale
Kristin Hannah
4.62 avg rating — 1.307.242 ratings
10.824
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
e:\project\webscrapping\scrap_for.py in line 38
     36 print(score)
     37 votes = td.findAll("div", {"style":"margin-top: 5px"})
---> 38 vote = votes[0].find("a", {"id":"loading_link_849498"}).text.strip()
     39 print(vote)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

I know that the "id":"loading_link_849498" is different for every book. I don't know how to get text in that tag  with different id. Are there any solution for this?
Thankyou before.

PS: I am sorry for my bad English, because English isn't my native language

Comment: `find("a", {"id":"loading_link_849498"})` clearly doesn't find an anchor with that id, and returns `None` - and `None` doesn't have a `.text` attribute, so you get that error. Start by looking at the value of `votes[0]` after the previous line. If you look at that value, you can tell it's mostly a bunch of JavaScript that hasn't executed - and that makes sense, because `urllib` and `bs4` can't do that. Like 90% of `bs4` questions on SO, the problem is that you need the JavaScript to run, and the solution is probably using something like `selenium`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I preferred the requests api and tested it as follows.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# URL of the Goodreads list
url = "https://www.goodreads.com/list/show/83612.NY_Times_Fiction_Best_Sellers_2015"

# Fetch the page
response = requests.get(url)
page_content = response.text

# Parse the HTML
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_content, "html.parser")

# Find all book entries.
books = soup.find_all("tr", itemtype="http://schema.org/Book")

for book in books:
    # Extracting title, author, and rating
    title = book.find("a", class_="bookTitle").text.strip()
    author = book.find("a", class_="authorName").text.strip()
    rating = book.find("span", class_="minirating").text.strip()

    # Extracting score 
    score_tag = book.find("a", onclick=lambda x: x and "Lightbox.showBoxByID('score_explanation'" in x)
    score = score_tag.text.split(': ')[1].replace(',', '') if score_tag else "N/A"

    # Extracting votes
    votes_tag = book.find("a", id=lambda x: x and x.startswith("loading_link_"))
    votes = votes_tag.text.split(' ')[0] if votes_tag else "N/A"


    # Print the extracted details
    print(f"Title: {title}")
    print(f"Author: {author}")
    print(f"Rating: {rating}")
    print(f"Score: {score}")
    print(f"Votes: {votes}")
    print("-" * 40)
```